# ajaxComplete issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

when below code executes it go to .ajaxComplete more than one time. Can i prevent this?

```
 $('.log').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
      if (settings.url == 'ajax/test.html') {
        alert('hi');
      }
    });
```

Only solution what I found is, make settings.url =  ''

```
 $('.log').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
      if (settings.url == 'ajax/test.html') {

settings.url =  '';
        alert('hi');
      }
    });
```

But I do not find it appropriate

Comment: you have more log class instances on the page?

Comment: show us the code where you make the ajax call please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen - check out this jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/XzJqL/

This may be happening if:

- There are other ajax requests - note that ajaxComplete gets called for any request (so e.g. some plugin on the page might be doing ajax in behind)
- You called ajaxComplete multiple times

Otherwise, it should be called only once, as in the jsfiddle demo.

Comment: yes it is going there more than one time...dont know why....and for same url only